# Cursor position issues after using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('balaashjquery'); ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function(){


     $('#iso').blur(function(){
      $isoval = $('#iso').val();
      if($isoval ==""){
       alert('iso field should not be empty');
      }
      $('#iso').focus();
    });
```

i have used similar type of jquery for all my fields .
now when i am leaving any field blank it is showing a validation message but after filling it i am not able to move to the next field either by using tab button nor mouse pointer

Comment: Because you told it to? You've essentially said, when the `#iso` input loses focus (`.blur`), give it focus again (`.focus`).

Answer (score 1):

Move the `.focus()` to inside your if statement:

```
$(function(){
     $('#iso').blur(function(){
      if($(this).val() ==""){
       alert('iso field should not be empty');
       $(this).focus();
      }
    });
```